# Probability of duplicates over time

Tags: probability

We have a set of $100$ unique types of items. Each item type has an infinite quantity of that item. Each day I get  $x$ number of random items from the set. None of those items will be the same as any others within the set of $x$. I accumulate these $x$ items day over day, but they always draw from the same pool of $100$ unique items.

What is the probability on any given day that I will get a duplicate of one of the items I’ve already gotten?

Comment: To clarify, it appears you are saying that you have a substantially large quantity of each of 100 different *types* of things and some sort of method to guarantee that the $x$ things that you draw each day will be of different types?

Comment: You're right. 100 types of items where the items within that type are infinite, and a guarantee that none of the $x$ you draw each day will be of the same type. Edited the original post for clarity

Comment: The varying answers bring up an interesting point. When you ask "what is the probability on any given day that I will get a duplicate of one of the items I’ve already gotten?", are we assuming that we haven't already gotten duplicates on a previous day?

Comment: That variation is why I specified the unconditional probability.  Your answer gives the conditional probability.  But it's fairly easy to see the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something of a generalization of the birthday problem (q.v.).

The probability of *no* duplicate after $n$ days is

$$
\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-x}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-2x}{100}\right)
\cdots
\left(\frac{100-(n-1)x}{100}\right)
$$

so the probability of at least one duplicate within $n$ days is $1$ minus all that, or

$$
1-
\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-x}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-2x}{100}\right)
\cdots
\left(\frac{100-(n-1)x}{100}\right)
$$

For $x$ not too large, this probability reaches $1/2$ at about day $n \doteq 12/\sqrt{x}$.

The unconditional probability that you get, *for the first time* on day $n$, a duplicate of an item you already got, is

$$
\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-x}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-2x}{100}\right)
\cdots
\left(\frac{100-(n-2)x}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{(n-1)x}{100}\right)
$$

since you must first go $n-1$ days without getting a duplicate, and then duplicate one of the $(n-1)x$ existing items on the $n$th day.

ETA: Obviously, we assume here that the pigeonhole principle has not been invoked—i.e., that $(n-1)x \leq 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the probability of getting a duplicate on day one is 0. On day two, duplicity happens if we draw any of the $x$ items from the day before, so there is an $\frac{x}{100}$ probability of getting a duplicate. Assuming we make it to day three without having already gotten a duplicate, we have now drawn $2x$ unique items, so there is now a $\frac{2 x}{100}$ probability of getting a duplicate. In general, the probability of getting a duplicate on day $n$ (assuming we haven't already gotten duplicates on a previous day) is $\frac{(n-1)\cdot x}{100}$ for applicable $n$. Obviously after a certain number of days we will have to get something we've gotten before by pigeon-hole principle.

Comment: I suppose this is following the assumption that $x$ is the same day after day.

Comment: That assumption is correct in this case